# Bigcommerce why is cart url different from other url

Tags: bigcommerce

I am developing my site with a bigcommerce stencil theme. My site's domain is 'www.mydomain.com', but my cart url is 'https://store-xxxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com/cart.php'. Why are they different?

Answer (score 1):

All BigCommerce stores are outfitted with an SSL certificate by default, which uses the .mybigcommerce.com subdomain.

As a result, your secure pages, like the cart and checkout page, will have a URL containing store-xxxxxx.mybigcommerce.com.
To have your store display your store's URL continuously throughout the checkout process, which often preferred by customers concerned about security, you can purchase a dedicated SSL certificate.

https://support.bigcommerce.com/articles/Public/Installing-an-SSL/

Comment: Got it. Thanks very much!